# Plotting classification results with confusion matrices on python

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I am performing least squares classification on my [data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ko_J0vu4k79VUQ6Wf0pJqyXx9TvtklfI?usp=sharing) and I was able to obtain my weights and I decided to plot a decision boundary line. However I require to use a confusion matrix to show my classification results. I was going to use `from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix` and I was going to assign `t` as my `prediction` however I am not sure how to obtain my `actual` results to work out the matrix. I have never plotted one so I might be getting all this wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.loadtxt("MyData_A.txt")
x=data[:,0:2] #the data points 
t=data[:,2] #class which data points belong to either 1s or 0s

x0=np.ones((len(x),1)) # creat array of ones as matrix (nx1) where n is number of points
X=np.append(x, x0, axis=1) # add column x0 to data

# w= ( (((X^T)X)^-1 )X^T )t           
XT_X=np.dot(X.T, X)              # (X^T)X
inv_XT_X=np.linalg.inv(XT_X)     # (X^T)X)^-1
X_tot=np.dot(inv_XT_X, X.T)      # ((X^T)X)^-1 )X^T
w=np.dot(X_tot, t)               # ( (((X^T)X)^-1 )X^T )t

x1_line = np.array([-1, 2])
x2_line = -w[2] / w[1] - (w[0] / w[1]) * x1_line

color_cond=['r' if t==1 else 'b' for t in t]
plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],color=color_cond)
plt.plot(x1_line,x2_line,color='k')
plt.xlabel('X1')
plt.ylabel('X2')
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.title('Training Data (X1,X2)')
plt.show()
```

The following is the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt0lc.jpg) obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

def predict(x1_line, x2_line, x):
    d = (x[0] - x1_line[0]) * (x2_line[1] - x2_line[0]) - (x[1] - x2_line[0]) * (x1_line[1] - x1_line[0])
    pred = 0 if d > 0 else 1
    return pred

preds = np.array([predict(x1_line, x2_line, x12) for x12 in x])

conf_mat = confusion_matrix(t, preds)
sns.heatmap(conf_mat, annot=True);
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you please explain what you are doing when calculating `d` ?

Comment: Sure, `d` is the "signed" distance  of the point `x` to your separator line given by the two points `(x1_line[0], x2_line[0])` and `(x1_line[1], x2_line[1])`, where the sign of the distance indicates which side of the separator line the point `x` lies - which is exactly your model 's prediction. I used this approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/274728/1024183

Answer (score 0):

[`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) and [`ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html) get the job done:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

data = np.loadtxt("MyData_A.txt")
X = data[:, :-1]
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
pred = clf.predict(X)
cm = confusion_matrix(y, pred)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm)
disp.plot()
```

[image]